# How to return different value, when transaction rollback?

Tags: java, spring, ssh, transactions

I use ssh framework to develop a web application.

There is an example of my transaction.

```
@Transactional
public StudentEntity addStudent(StudentEntity studentEntity) {
       return studentDAO.save(studentEntity);
}
```

Now, I want to **return null** when **exception** is thrown and then transaction rollback.

Comment: Or should I catch the Exception out of the transaction,instead of change the return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is not advised to return `null`.

If you anticipate any `Exception` from your logic you should inform the caller via `throws` clause so that they are prepared for such scenarios.

Regarding rollback you should consider below update to your `@Transactional` annotation

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

Do note that this will rollback transaction after throwing any exception.

Comment: If I add **@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)**,is the exception still thrown out of the method?Or be caught by transaction?

Comment: It will be thrown. Do read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back) for further details on rollback.

Answer (score 1):

To rollback transaction programatically take a look at `TransactionAspectSupport` class.

```
@Transactional
public StudentEntity addStudent(StudentEntity studentEntity) {
      try {
       return studentDAO.save(studentEntity);
        }
      catch(Exception ex) {
       //set transaction for rollback.
      TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
     }
}
```

You could do it declarative manner

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={SomeSpecificException.class, SomeOtherSpecificException.class})
```